# MongoDB .NET Driver 2.4 match stage

Tags: .net, mongodb, driver

In Robomongo, the following query works and returns all documents where customer name or country contains 'Acushnet'.

```
db.getCollection('plants').aggregate([
 $match: { 
     $or  : 
     [
        { 
            'customerName.Name.value' : /Acushnet/
        },
        { 
            'country.CountryName' : /Acushnet/
        }
     ]
 }
])
```

In my .NET example, I add the exact same match stage:

```
        var matchStage = new BsonDocument
        {
            {
                "$match", new BsonDocument
                {
                    {
                        "$or", new BsonArray
                        {
                                new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    {
                                    "customerName.Name.value", "/" + term + "/"
                                    }
                                },
                                new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    {
                                        "country.countryName", "/" + term + "/"
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        pipe.AppendStage<BsonDocument>(matchStage);
```

Term is a placeholder for my search term ('acushnet'). For me both examples are the same, but the second one returns ALL documents. The first one only returns four documents - the ones which contain Acushnet.

Why does the .NET driver differs from the query I send with Robomongo?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. Robomongo searches an array automatically through the dot-notation and because customer.Name is an array, this works.
The .net driver does not allow this, so I needed to use $elemMatch:

```
        var matchStage = new BsonDocument
        {
            {
                "$or" , new BsonArray 
                    {
                        new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {
                                        "customerName", new BsonDocument
                                          {
                                                {
                                                    "$elemMatch", new BsonDocument
                                                    {
                                                        {
                                                            "Name", new BsonDocument
                                                            {
                                                                {
                                                                    "$elemMatch", new BsonDocument {
                                                                        {
                                                                            "value", "Sunprene"
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                         }
                            }
                        },
                        new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {
                                    "country" , new BsonDocument
                                    {
                                        {
                                            "$elemMatch", new BsonDocument
                                            {
                                                {
                                                    "CountryName", "United States"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }                                            
                    }                     
            }
        };
```